# Differences between two sentences (Any vs All Possible)

Tags: meaning-in-context, difference

Considering the following two sentences, is there a difference between them? If so, do "all possible" and "any" make the difference?

**Note**, serializable and serial schedules are two different types of schedules in distributed database systems. However, the word "equivalent" here means that they give the same results when executing a set of transactions. For example, given that a is a serializable schedule and b is serial. They are equivalent if they execute the same set of transactions and give the same results.

> - "A serializable schedule ensures that the execution of n
>     transactions is equivalent to all possible serial schedules of
>     the same n transactions."
> - "Formally, a schedule S of n transactions is serializable if it is
>     equivalent to any serial schedule of the same n transactions"

In other words, can I say that the meaning of the former sentence is different than the latter one?

Thanks!

Comment: Other close voters felt that you should have included more information in your question - the [Details, Please](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please) post on [meta] has some good advice for avoiding those sorts of close votes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok first of all, using a different example, there can be a clear difference between "any" and "all" in certain contexts:

> My son will eat **any** of the cakes.
>
> My son will eat **all** of the cakes.

In this example both imply that there is a limited selection of cakes on offer because it says "*the* cakes". Using "any" means that all of the cakes are an option, and that the son can select and eat a cake from all those on offer; whereas the second using "all" implies that he will eat every single one of them himself. In this context where there is a limited scope, the two have completely different meanings.

Thing is, in *your* example it isn't simply the difference between "any" and "all":

> ..is equivalent to **all possible** serial schedules..
>
> ..is equivalent to **any** serial schedule..

It is actually the difference between "**any**" and "**all *possible***".

I don't fully understand the subject in your examples so let me use another one:

> The app works with **any** model of smartphone
>
> The app works with **all possible** models of smartphone

In this example, the first using "*any*" implies that it is a universally compatible app. A scope has not been set as it was in the cake example where it implied a limited selection of cakes. It doesn't say "any smartphone *currently on the market*". So this implies, rightly or wrongly, that the app will work on future smartphones too - literally *any* phone.

Saying "all" smartphones doesn't strictly define a scope either, but the word "all" does imply a countable number, so arguably this does not cover phones that could be made in the future. However, saying "all *possible*" smartphones completely removes any possible limitation. It implies that any smartphone that could possibly emerge in the future would work with this app as well.

So no, there is no *clear* difference in your two examples, because of the inclusion of the word "possible". "Any" does not define a limited scope, and "all possible" removes any inference of one.